# Multiple controls with the same ID 'sub_topic_id' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: asp.net

Pls help

```
`<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id"><EditItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id")%>>`
`</asp:TextBox></EditItemTemplate>`<ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
                        <asp:Hyperlink  ID="sub_topic_id" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# "hohrotherexecview.aspx?id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("id").ToString())%>'
                        Text='<%# Eval("id")%>' Target="_self" />`</ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CLOSED" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign = "Center">
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox  ID="ApproveBox" runat="server"   />
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>`
```

when i am selecting multiple ids its showing error "Multiple controls with the same ID 'sub_topic_id' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs." Pls help

Comment: Dim id_label As Label = DirectCast(row_check.FindControl("Label1"), Label)